# Libgdx проблема с актерами

Tags: libgdx

У меня в активити есть актер, который должен двигаться по нажатию на кнопку, двигаться не однократно, а пока я кнопку не отпущу. Сейчасполучается двигать лищь однократно. Отправьте плиз кусок кода, в котором решается эта проблема

```
public class Plane extends Actor {

    public static Sprite sprite;
    static Rectangle plan;

    public Plane() {

        sprite = new Sprite(Resource.plane);     

        sprite.setBounds(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());

        setBounds(bounds.width / 2 - 32, 30, 64, 64);

        plan=new Rectangle();
        plan.x=bounds.width/2-64/2;
        plan.y=30;
        plan.width=60;
        plan.height=60;

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        sprite.draw(batch); 
    }

    @Override
    public void act(final float delta) {
        sprite.setBounds(plan.x, plan.y, getWidth(), getHeight());


if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) plan.x-=delta*300;
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) plan.x+=delta*300;
    }

}
```

И в главном классе:

```
LEFT l=new LEFT();
l.addListener(new ClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
        Plane.plan.x-=300*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }

});
stage.addActor(l);

RIGHT r=new RIGHT();
r.addListener(new ClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
        Plane.plan.x+=300*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }
});
stage.addActor(r);
```

Comment: Покажите плиз ваш кусок кода.

Comment: чтобы дополнить/исправить вопрос, нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: У вас, получается, при повторном нажатии на кнопку, ничего не происходит?